# jQuery .on Click second time not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

```
var elms = $('.selector', list);
elms.off();
elms.on('vclick', function(event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var elm = $(this);
        customEventHandler(elm, elm.attr("id"));
});
```

If I bind the click event via `$('.selector', list).on('click',...)` to an element in a list, it is working fine.

If I add elements after doing `.append()` to the list and calling again `$('.selector', list).on('click',...)` no click is triggered. Even if I use `.off()` before to remove old events.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: What is c.onclick? Is that a constants variable? I think the first thing to the .on() function needs to be a string that maps to an event name. Like "click".

Comment: Do you refresh list after appending elements?

Comment: Yes the list.trigger("create"); after binding events...

Comment: `$('.selector).listview('refresh')` not create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the problem, I had to bind the events after calling list.trigger("create"); instead of before, maybe this is helpful for anyone...

Answer (score 5):

Try this way:- <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W3pnJ/)</kbd>

```
$('.container').on('click', '.selector', function(event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var elm = $(this);
        alert(elm.index());
});
```

You can achieve this using `delegated events` approach.

> **Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time**. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This element could be the container element of a view in a Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The document element is available in the head of the document before loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without waiting for the document to be ready.

Comment: this seams the cause, I wil check delegated event approach!

Comment: Nope, as already using vclick, event if using the delegated approach, no event trigger after append and running the same bind methods.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `c.onclick` with 'click'. Use the right format.

```
$('.container').on('click', '.selector', function(event, ui) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var elm = $(this);
    alert(elm.index());
});
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that c.onclick is a kind of constant to JQM vclick. I edit my post.